# Change image after each 10seconds in WPF image box

Tags: wpf-controls

There is a requirement of updating image in image boxes of WPF. I am thinking of creating a list with all the paths and then using a timer control checking the 10 seconds. After the 10 seconds has elapsed the next id from list is taken and bound to the image box. I am new to WPF. Can any one help me with a working example.

Comment: How much of that do you already know how to do? Which part are you having trouble with?

Comment: I have done so far to bind a single image to image box.

Answer (score 0):

Use a [`DispatcherTimer`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.threading.dispatchertimer.aspx) to invoke a method at regular intervalls. In this method change the bound image, remember to raise the `INotifyPropertyChanged` event to let WPF know it should query the bound property again.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the reply but did it by using Timer_Elapsed() event.The below code is placed in the lapsed event.
    Action action = () => BindToImages(lststr);
                Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(action); 
                  _timer.Start();

Answer (score 0):

Hi i have made thig running with the below code .

```
private void timer_Elapsed(object sender,System.Timers.ElapsedEventArgs e)
    {

        Action action1 = () => this.BeginStoryboard((Storyboard)this.FindResource("BlinkStoryboardFed"));
        Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(action1);
        Action action = () => BindToImages(lststr);
        Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(action);
        //BindToImages(lststr);
        _timer.Start();
    }

public void BindToImages(List<string> lststrpath)
    {
        lock (_locker)
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < lststrpath.Count; i++)
            {
                if (count == 0)
                {
                    startindex = i;
                    this.BindToImgIndx = startindex;
                    AppState.Index = i;
                    BitmapImage img = new BitmapImage();
                    img.BeginInit();
                    img.UriSource = new Uri(lststrpath[startindex].ToString(), UriKind.Relative);
                    img.CacheOption = BitmapCacheOption.OnLoad;
                    img.EndInit();
                    image1.Source = img;
                    count++;
                }
                else
                {
                    int k = AppState.Index;
                    k = ++k;
                    this.BindToImgIndx = startindex;
                    if (k < lststrpath.Count)
                    {
                        BitmapImage img = new BitmapImage();
                        img.BeginInit();
                        img.UriSource = new Uri(lststrpath[k].ToString(), UriKind.Relative);
                        img.CacheOption = BitmapCacheOption.OnLoad;
                        img.EndInit();
                        image1.Source = img;
                    }
                    AppState.Index = k;
                }
                this.BeginStoryboard((Storyboard)this.FindResource("BlinkStoryboardUnFed"));
                break; 
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: this does not answer the question. You should edit your question if you have aditional information to share. Please read the faq at http://stackoverflow.com/faq