# Change images in box

Tags: wpf, xaml

I'm still learning WPF and I need small help, hope someone would be able to help me out. 
So my question, is there any way to make in wpf some picturebox that will automatically change 3 images? So example when i run application it shows 1 picture then after 2 seconds it changes to another and so on?

Okay so i added like this:
XAML Code:
`<Image x:Name="slider" Stretch="Fill" Source="Slider/slide1.png"/>`

And cs:

```
private void MainForm_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            var dispatcherTimer = new DispatcherTimer();
            dispatcherTimer.Tick += new EventHandler(dispatcherTimer_Tick);
            dispatcherTimer.Interval = new TimeSpan(0, 0, 1);
            dispatcherTimer.Start();
        }

    private void dispatcherTimer_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {


    }
```

Now how to make it changing sliders on tick?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9226514/change-image-after-each-10seconds-in-wpf-image-box

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can directly animate source property from xaml itself check the below code

```
    <Grid Height="200" Width="200">
        <Grid.Triggers>
            <EventTrigger RoutedEvent="Loaded">
                <BeginStoryboard >
                    <Storyboard  >
                        <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Duration="00:00:06"  RepeatBehavior="Forever"  Storyboard.TargetName="img1" Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Image.Source)">
                            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="00:00:00">
                                <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame.Value>
                                    <BitmapImage UriSource="image1.png" />
                                </DiscreteObjectKeyFrame.Value>
                            </DiscreteObjectKeyFrame>
                            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="00:00:02">
                                <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame.Value>
                                    <BitmapImage UriSource="image2.png" />
                                </DiscreteObjectKeyFrame.Value>
                            </DiscreteObjectKeyFrame>
                            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="00:00:04">
                                <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame.Value>
                                    <BitmapImage UriSource="image3.png" />
                                </DiscreteObjectKeyFrame.Value>
                            </DiscreteObjectKeyFrame>
                        </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                    </Storyboard>
                </BeginStoryboard>
            </EventTrigger>
        </Grid.Triggers>
        <Image x:Name="img1" Stretch="Fill"></Image>
    </Grid>
```

**Update**

i don't think you can animate image source with storyboard so you have to take 3 images and animate there visibility property

To load images asynchronously you have to binding, for binding you can create property or else you can pass image path through converter parameter

```
   <Grid  Height="200" Width="200">
        <Grid.Triggers>
            <EventTrigger RoutedEvent="Loaded">
                <BeginStoryboard >
                    <Storyboard Duration="00:00:06" RepeatBehavior="Forever"  >
                        <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Duration="00:00:03"    Storyboard.TargetName="img1" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Visibility">
                            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="00:00:00" Value="{x:Static Visibility.Visible}"/>
                            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="00:00:02" Value="{x:Static Visibility.Collapsed}"/>
                        </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                        <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames BeginTime="00:00:02"    Storyboard.TargetName="img2" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Visibility">
                            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="00:00:00" Value="{x:Static Visibility.Visible}"/>
                            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="00:00:02" Value="{x:Static Visibility.Collapsed}"/>
                        </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                        <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames BeginTime="00:00:04"    Storyboard.TargetName="img3" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Visibility">
                            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="00:00:00" Value="{x:Static Visibility.Visible}"/>
                            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="00:00:02" Value="{x:Static Visibility.Collapsed}"/>
                        </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                    </Storyboard>
                </BeginStoryboard>
            </EventTrigger>
        </Grid.Triggers>
        <Image x:Name="img1" Visibility="Collapsed" Source="{Binding IsAsync=True,  Converter={StaticResource ImgConverter}, ConverterParameter=http://mydomain.com/image3.png}" />
        <Image x:Name="img2" Visibility="Collapsed" Source="{Binding IsAsync=True,  Converter={StaticResource ImgConverter}, ConverterParameter=http://mydomain.com/image2.png}" />
        <Image x:Name="img3" Visibility="Collapsed" Source="{Binding IsAsync=True,  Converter={StaticResource ImgConverter}, ConverterParameter=http://mydomain.com/image1.png}" />
    </Grid>
```

Converter:

```
 public class ImgConverter : IValueConverter
 {
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
    {
        if (parameter != null)
        {
            BitmapImage bi = new BitmapImage();
            bi.BeginInit();
            bi.UriSource = new Uri(parameter.ToString(), UriKind.Absolute);
            bi.CacheOption = BitmapCacheOption.OnLoad;
            bi.EndInit();
            return bi;
        }
            return null;
    }
    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
 }
```

Comment: Ohh thank you very much, this is much better! But will it work if i put `<BitmapImage UriSource="http://mydomain.com/image1.png" />` ?

Comment: I wanted but i can't i need more than 15 reputation :/

Comment: No problem, i will have soon more questions about wpf. Maybe you could help me out?

Comment: if you can mail me on udev[at]programmer[dot]net

Comment: On first one code is it possible to make fade in and fade out effect?

Answer (score 0):

```
private void dispatcherTimer_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    BitmapImage image = new BitmapImage();
    image.BeginInit();
    image.UriSource = new Uri("pack://application:,,,/YourAppName;component/someimage.png");
    image.EndInit();

    this.myImage.Source = image;
}
```

Manipulating WPF elements directly isn't good form though, to do "proper" WPF you should be using MVVM.

Comment: okay so i have fixed it with cases making if case 1 then slider1 if case2 put slider 2 and same for case 3 :) now is it possible to load image from URL not from app folder?

Comment: Yes, a Uri will accept as well, as described in [the MSDN documentation for it](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.uri(v=vs.110).aspx).